Mariadb upgrade from 10.3 to 10.11
Is it possible to upgrade from Maria 10.3 to 10.11. What are the necessary steps or any script that can be followed? Also I’m planning to upgrade my os from rhel7 to 8, what additional steps should I follow? I have galera enabled with encryption and ssl

It’s installed via yum. Yes I did while it says it is possible to go from 10.3 to 10.11, I’m curious on the backup and restore strategy in case I have to rebuild the os node

Ref upgrade guide.
There are some notes of differences between MariaDB versions. Based on your decision to go ahead you've either tested 10.11 first and/or are willing to do any quick work to make sure its compatible.
Keep a backup first.
Ensure all nodes are cleanly shutdown first (there is a shutdown complete message).
Because SST between different MariaDB versions (and galera versions) isn't allowed it will be a cluster shutdown and upgrade each node (OS + MariaDB) and then start again. Don't have an old MariaDB version and a new MariaDB version running in the cluster.
After notes are primary, run mariadb-upgrade to ensure that system tables are update to expose the new features available in the later version.
If you get stuck - see getting help.
